# Xcode preprocessor macros to include system style headers

Tags: c++, c, xcode, build-system, freetype2

I'm trying to manually add freetype 2.9.0 as a framework build target to my toy project in Xcode. Freetype uses preprocessor macros to include its headers with angled brackets (`<freetype/config/xx.h>`) which is confusing the Xcode build system and I get the error `expected "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>`, indicating that it can't find my system level includes. Instead of hardcoding the subfolder headers, how would I configure the Xcode build system to find these config files?

I tried this in another file

```
#define SOME_CONFIG <glfw/glfw3.h> /*this header is included as a system header in a subfolder <project/glfw/... , and works fine*/

#ifdef SOME_CONFIG
#include SOME_CONFIG
#endif
```

And it works perfectly. But when I try this with freetype it cannot find the  expanded in the macros.

The freetype include structure looks like this:

```
include/ftbuild.h         -- points to include/freetype/config/ftheader.h
include/config/ftheader.h -- has all the #define macros to ->
include/config/...        -- a bunch of headers with options which Xcode refuse to see
```

Comment: You can add additional include directories by passing `-I…` flags to the compiler. For example, `-Ifreetype/config`. No idea how to tell xcode to do that, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it was actually working all along I just forgot to add the environment variable FT2_BUILD_LIBRARY to both debug and release build, and I had it set to debug, so the internal header macros was not being precompiled, and therefore not found. Works perfectly fine to do what I am trying to do in Xcode 9.

[image: Environment varialbes]